# Why javascript is returning NaN when I place variables outside the function?

Tags: javascript

Do you guys know whyn when I place this varables outside the functions, the result is "Not a Number"?.

Dont variables should become "Global" when placed ouside a function?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// V-LOXY > Variaveis Calculo de Frete

var Comp = document.getElementById('ComprimenTo').value;
var Larg = document.getElementById('Largura').value;
var Alt = document.getElementById('Altura').value;
var TxCubagem = 300

function PesoCubado(){

document.getElementById('PesoCub').innerHTML = ((Comp/100)*(Larg/100)*(Alt/100)*TxCubagem).toFixed(1)+' kg';
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<label>Comprimento [cm]:
<input id='ComprimenTo' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
<p></p>
<label>Largura [cm]:
<input id='Largura' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
<p></p>
<label>Altura [cm]:
<input id='Altura' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
<p></p>       
<input type='button' onclick='PesoCubado()' value="Calcular" >
<p></p>

<p>Peso Cubado: <b id='PesoCub'></b> </p>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Weird; given that your `<script>` is placed before your elements and doesn’t wait for them to exist, I’d think it would just throw an error immediately.

Comment: Assuming that your example here doesn’t *quite* represent your actual code, though, it’ll likely be because you’re reading the `value`s of the inputs before they’re filled in.

Comment: @Ryan, how can I correct it?

Comment: Don’t try to get their values outside your function?

Comment: I just wrote them after body, now its working!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things: move your script to below your elements that you are trying to do work on (right before end of body closing), and grab the `value` of the inputs during the `PesoCubado()` function invocation:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <label>Comprimento [cm]:
  <input id='ComprimenTo' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
  <p></p>
  <label>Largura [cm]:
  <input id='Largura' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
  <p></p>
  <label>Altura [cm]:
  <input id='Altura' type="number" width="15"/></label><br />
  <p></p>       
  <input type='button' onclick='PesoCubado()' value="Calcular" >
  <p></p>

  <p>Peso Cubado: <b id='PesoCub'></b> </p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var CompElem = document.getElementById('ComprimenTo');
    var LargElem = document.getElementById('Largura');
    var AltElem = document.getElementById('Altura');
    var PesoCubElem = document.getElementById('PesoCub');
    var TxCubagem = 300

    function PesoCubado(){
      PesoCubElem.innerHTML = ((CompElem.value/100)*(LargElem.value/100)*(AltElem.value/100)*TxCubagem).toFixed(1)+' kg';
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great!! Great! It's works very fine now. Thks a lot hackerrdave

Answer (score 0):

You've got several problems with your script, which are:

- your variables point to the initial value of the text fields, and as such, won't be using the latest value. You should get the values of each field within your `PesoCubado` function.
- Values returned from inputs are always strings and as such, you'll have to convert them to a number using the `Number` function.
- You'd be best wrapping your code in a `load` event listener on the `window` to ensure your page is loaded fully.

Hopefully this helps.

Tom

Comment: Thks a Lot Tom! Works fine when I followed ur tips :)